# ADP FTP Linked Service losing connection mid-file transfer

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from an (azure vm) ftp hosted .csv file. When i execute the data pipeline i can see the ftp log and it initiates the file transfer, but at ~11mb it servers, attempts to reconnects, successfully reconnects, but then immediately disconnects.

Has anyone encountered this?

I can successfully transfer the file from cyberduck to local machine - and if i delete a lot of data from the csv, making it much smaller in size, the pipeline works correctly.

I have gone through passive ftp settings and vm firewall settings but i still cannot successfully get the file to completely transfer.

Answer (score 0):

I realized this is not a data transfer issue but a file format issue. It seem like the FTP transfer protocol doesn't download the entire file and then load - it seems to do partials and there was a piece of it that was breaking (double quotes in a string and double quote identifier")

So it's an issue but a different issue and not related to this question.